# Check buff if same then add them together

Tags: c#, list, math

this is kind of complicated but I will try to explain it.
what I am doing is giving cards with random buffs each of them have 3 different buff
positive buff, negative buff and random buff. if there is a buff duplicated in the same card I want  to add them together.
example:

**Example From:**

[image: From]

**Example To:**

[image: To]

**The Code:**

```
        string[] ChoosenBuff = new string[3]; // To Store All Choosen Buffs

        // All Buffs
        string[] PositiveBuffs = { "+5 Max HP", "+10 Max HP" };
        string[] RandomBuffs = { "+3 Max HP", "-3% FireRate" };
        string[] negativeBuffs = {"-4% FireRate", "-6% FireRate"};

        // Pick Random Buff
        int BuffChance1 = Random.Range(0, PositiveBuffs.Length);
        int BuffChance2 = Random.Range(0, RandomBuffs.Length);
        int BuffChance3 = Random.Range(0, NagitiveBuffs.Length);

        // Store The Buffs
        ChoosenBuff[0] = PositiveBuffs[BuffChance1];
        ChoosenBuff[1] = RandomBuffs[BuffChance2];
        ChoosenBuff[2] = NagitiveBuffs[BuffChance3];

        foreach (string i in ChoosenBuff)
        {
            // To Display The Buffs On The Card Text
            CardText.text = ChoosenBuff;
        }
```

is there a way to cut and separate the numbers from the string then add the numbers together then put them back together.
sorry if my explanation is super bad.

Comment: I'd suggest to not use strings and parsing data, rather separate the buff into separate object and define the properties - buff type (HP, attack speed, range), buff value (integer value), value type (flat or percentage). Then you can make much easier selection for the calculations,

Comment: For your info, Bing chat tells me that: In card games, buffs are temporary or permanent effects that increase the power of a card or a player.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to use some types to describe your buffs, for example:

```
public enum BuffType{ MaxHp, FireRate}
public record Buff(BuffType Type, double Value);
```

This lets you group buffs together, for example

```
var mergedBuffs = allBuffs
    .GroupBy(b => b.Type)
    .Select(group => new Buff(group.Key, group.Sum(b => b.Value));
```

You could also a separate class for each type of buff, with a common interface. This does have some advantages, such as letting you put the code associated with a buff inside the class itself. But also some potential downsides, like being more difficult to store in a database. I would recommend reading Eric Lipperts articles on [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) for some insight into the problems designing a object model for a game.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using strings for the buffs and their values which is going to make it difficult to work with the numbers.

You should create a method that applies the buff and takes in a parameter of how much health or damage needs to be applied. It sounds a bit challenging but it's easier than splitting the strings up and looking for numbers and symbols; that will be a lot more code.

Here's an example where you create the method inside the class Card

```
public class Card
{
     private int health;

     private void TakeDamage(int damageAmount)
     {
     health -= damageAmount;
     }
}
```

When you do something that does damage, that method will return the amount of damage. TakeDamage(int damageAmount); will take that parameter in and make that calculation for you.

I hope that's helpful to you in some way. If it isn't exactly what you're looking for, I'm sorry.

If it is what you're looking for, but seems a bit confusing or overwhelming, start with just a health property for your cards, have them damage each other; once that system is working, you can add a powerup that multiplies the damage or adds to it. That will get you moving towards building a complex systems of buffs.